# firebase database in unity editor is not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access to my firebase database like this

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/");
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

It's work fine in my android device ,but it's not working in the editor.
I am getting this exception

```
WebSocket: ws_12 - WebSocketException during handshake
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the **FirebaseDatabase.dll** for Editor platform under

```
Assets/Firebase/Plugins/Mono/
```

Then enable the **FirebaseDatabase.dll** under

```
Assets/Firebase/Plugins/
```

I don't know how clean this solution, but it works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference reference;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing is happening with me, just reverse it. Reference is working fine in the editor but not on an android device. I checked for the access to the DLL it has been provided in editor and android both.